# Necessary proxy exception list for RHEL updates

Tags: linux, proxy, redhat, yum, update

Anyone know if I need to allow more than *.rhn.redhat.com on 443 & 80 via a proxy exception to allow my RHEL servers to go out and grab updates ? Haven't received the hardware yet, but I'm just trying to get my the list of exceptions to my network team in advance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

80 and 443 to xmlrpc.rhn.redhat.com.

For more information:

https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/solutions/11214

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate this. Tried to rep you, but I didn't have the points to do so..